# Winsock2 Why is acknowledgement message from server to client talking long time in UDP socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, winsock

I am trying to write a file transfer program using `winsock2` using UDP socket. The file is transferred in blocks and I am trying to implement a Go Back N algorithm for failure handling. Here is my server code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
#include<winsock2.h>

#define PORT 8080
#define MAXLEN 1024
#define BLOCKSIZE 15
#define SEQNUMSIZE 2
#define DATALENSIZE 2

bool WriteToFile(char block[], std::ofstream& file, int n, int &expSeqNum, char seqnumchr[])
{
    int i=0;
    //char seqnumchr[SEQNUMSIZE+1];
    strncpy(seqnumchr, block, SEQNUMSIZE);
    seqnumchr[SEQNUMSIZE] = '\0';
    int seqnum = std::stoi(seqnumchr);
    if(seqnum != expSeqNum)
    {
        expSeqNum = seqnum;
        return seqnum==-1?true:false;
    }
    
    printf("Sequence Number: %d exp %d\n", seqnum, expSeqNum);
    char datalenchr[DATALENSIZE+1];
    strncpy(datalenchr, block+SEQNUMSIZE, DATALENSIZE);
    datalenchr[DATALENSIZE] = '\0';
    int datalen = std::stoi(datalenchr);
    char data[datalen+1];
    strncpy(data, block+SEQNUMSIZE+DATALENSIZE, datalen);
    data[datalen] = '\0';
    file.write(data, datalen);

    return false;
}


int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET serverSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN serverAddr;
    char buffer[MAXLEN];
    SOCKADDR_IN clientAddr;
    int clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
    
    int bytesReceived;

    std::ofstream file("server.txt");


    if( WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        printf("Server: WSAStartup failed with error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Server: The Winsock DLL status is %s.\n", wsaData.szSystemStatus);
    }

    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if(serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Server: Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else { printf("Server: socket() is OK!\n"); }

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    { 
        printf("Server: bind() failed! Error: %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(serverSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else { printf("Server: bind() is OK!\n"); }

    getsockname(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, (int *)sizeof(serverAddr));
    printf("Server: Receiving IP(s) used: %s\n", inet_ntoa(serverAddr.sin_addr));
    printf("Server: Receiving port used: %d\n", htons(serverAddr.sin_port));

    
    bytesReceived = recvfrom(serverSocket, buffer, MAXLEN, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize);
    if(bytesReceived <= 0)
    {
        printf("Server: Connection closed with error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        buffer[bytesReceived] = '\0';
        if(strcmp(buffer, "upload")==0)
        {
            printf("File upload started...\n");
            sendto(serverSocket, "start", 5, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddr, clientAddrSize);
            int expSeqNum = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                bytesReceived = recvfrom(serverSocket, buffer, MAXLEN, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize);
                if(bytesReceived <= 0)
                {
                    printf("Server: Connection closed with error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                }
                else 
                {
                    int tempExpNum = expSeqNum;
                    char seqnumchr[SEQNUMSIZE+1];
                    if(WriteToFile(buffer, file, bytesReceived, expSeqNum, seqnumchr))
                    {
                        printf("File upload finished!\n");                        
                        break;
                    }
                    if(expSeqNum != -1 && expSeqNum <= tempExpNum)
                    {
                        printf("Ack sent %d\n",expSeqNum);
                        if(expSeqNum == tempExpNum) expSeqNum++;
                        else expSeqNum = tempExpNum;
                        
                        u_long mode = 1; 
                        ioctlsocket(serverSocket, FIONBIO, &mode);
                        sendto(serverSocket, seqnumchr, SEQNUMSIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddr, clientAddrSize);
                        mode = 0;
                        ioctlsocket(serverSocket, FIONBIO, &mode);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    getpeername(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize);
    printf("Server: Sending IP used: %s\n", inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr));
    printf("Server: Sending port used: %d\n", htons(clientAddr.sin_port));
    
    if (closesocket(serverSocket) != 0)
        printf("Server: closesocket() failed! Error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());

    else
        printf("Server: closesocket() is OK\n");

    printf("Server: Cleaning up...\n");
    if(WSACleanup() != 0)
        printf("Server: WSACleanup() failed! Error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("Server: WSACleanup() is OK\n");

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my client code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
#include<map>
#include<iterator>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<winsock2.h>

#define PORT 8080
#define MAXLEN 1024
#define BLOCKSIZE 15
#define SEQNUMSIZE 2
#define DATALENSIZE 2
#define WINDOWSIZE 3
#define BLOCKTIMEOUT 10


bool ReadBlockFromFile(char str[], std::ifstream& file, int seqNum)
{
    std::string seqN = std::to_string(seqNum);
    seqN = std::string(SEQNUMSIZE - seqN.length(), '0') + seqN;

    strcpy(str, seqN.c_str());

    int datalen = BLOCKSIZE - SEQNUMSIZE - DATALENSIZE;
    char data[datalen];
    file.read(data, datalen);
    bool eof = false;
    if(file.eof())
    {
        eof = true;
        if(file.gcount() != datalen)
        {
            std::string app(datalen - file.gcount(), '0');
            strcat(data, app.c_str());
            datalen = file.gcount();
        }
    }
    std::string dataL = std::to_string(datalen);
    dataL = std::string(DATALENSIZE - dataL.length(), '0') + dataL;
    strcat(str, dataL.c_str());
    strcat(str, data);
    std::cout<<seqNum<<std::endl;
    return eof?true:false;
}

void CheckAck(SOCKET& clientSocket, SOCKADDR_IN& serverAddr, std::map<int,std::pair<int,std::string>>& nonAckTimeData)
{
    //printf("CheckAck\n");
    u_long mode = 1; 
    ioctlsocket(clientSocket, FIONBIO, &mode);
    char buffer[MAXLEN];
    int serverAddrSize = sizeof(serverAddr);
    while (true)
    {
        int n = recvfrom(clientSocket, buffer, MAXLEN, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, &serverAddrSize);
        if(n ==-1)
        {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            if(err != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                printf("Client: recvfrom() failed with error code %d\n",err);
            }
            break;
        }
        buffer[n] = '\0';
        char seqN[SEQNUMSIZE+1];
        strncpy(seqN, buffer, SEQNUMSIZE);
        seqN[SEQNUMSIZE] = '\0';
        int seqNum = std::stoi(seqN);
        printf("Sequence number %d acknowledgement received\n", seqNum);
        nonAckTimeData.erase(seqNum);
    } 
    mode = 0; 
    ioctlsocket(clientSocket, FIONBIO, &mode);
    for(std::map<int,std::pair<int,std::string>>::iterator it = nonAckTimeData.begin(); it != nonAckTimeData.end(); it++)
    {
        it->second .first++;
        if(it->second.first > BLOCKTIMEOUT)
        {
            printf("Sequence number %d timeouted!\n", it->first);
            for(std::map<int,std::pair<int,std::string>>::iterator it1 = it; it1 != nonAckTimeData.end(); it1++)
            {
                sendto(clientSocket, it1->second.second.c_str(), it1->second.second.size(), 0, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, serverAddrSize);
                it1->second.first = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET clientSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN serverAddr, srcInfo;
    char buffer[MAXLEN];
    int serverAddrSize = sizeof(serverAddr);
    
    std::ifstream file("client.txt");

    std::map<int,std::pair<int,std::string>> nonAckTimeData;
    bool endFile = false;

    if( WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        printf("Client: WSAStartup failed with error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Client: The Winsock DLL status is %s.\n", wsaData.szSystemStatus);
    }

    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if(clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Client: Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else { printf("Client: socket() is OK!\n"); }

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    sendto(clientSocket, "upload", 6, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, serverAddrSize);
    int n = recvfrom(clientSocket, buffer, MAXLEN, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, &serverAddrSize);
    if(n <= 0)
    {
        printf("Client: Connection closed with error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        buffer[n] = '\0';
        if(strcmp(buffer, "start")==0)
        {
            printf("File upload started...\n");
            int seqNum = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                int ackLen = nonAckTimeData.size();
                if(ackLen < WINDOWSIZE)
                {
                    if(!endFile)
                    {
                        bool endF = ReadBlockFromFile(buffer, file, seqNum);
                        sendto(clientSocket, buffer, BLOCKSIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, serverAddrSize);
                        nonAckTimeData[seqNum] = std::make_pair(0, buffer);
                        if(endF)
                        {  
                            endFile = endF;
                        }
                        seqNum ++;
                    }
                    else if(ackLen == 0)
                    {
                        std::string endFileAck = "-1" + std::string(BLOCKSIZE - 2, '0');
                        sendto(clientSocket, endFileAck.c_str(), BLOCKSIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, serverAddrSize);
                        break;
                    }
                        
                }
                CheckAck(clientSocket, serverAddr, nonAckTimeData);
                
            }
        }
    }
    memset(&srcInfo, 0, sizeof(srcInfo));

    int len = sizeof(srcInfo);
    getsockname(clientSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&srcInfo, &len);

    printf("Client: Sending IP(s) used: %s\n", inet_ntoa(srcInfo.sin_addr));
    printf("Client: Sending port used: %d\n", htons(srcInfo.sin_port));
 
    getpeername(clientSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, (int *)sizeof(serverAddr));

    printf("Client: Receiving IP used: %s\n", inet_ntoa(serverAddr.sin_addr));
    printf("Client: Receiving port used: %d\n", htons(serverAddr.sin_port));

    printf("Client: Finished sending. Closing the sending socket...\n");
 
    if (closesocket(clientSocket) != 0)
        printf("Client: closesocket() failed! Error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("Server: closesocket() is OK\n");

    printf("Client: Cleaning up...\n");

    if(WSACleanup() != 0)
        printf("Client: WSACleanup() failed! Error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("Client: WSACleanup() is OK\n");

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the server output:

```
Server: The Winsock DLL status is Running.
Server: socket() is OK!
Server: bind() is OK!
Server: Receiving IP(s) used: 0.0.0.0
Server: Receiving port used: 8080
File upload started...
Sequence Number: 0 exp 0
Ack sent 0
Sequence Number: 1 exp 1
Ack sent 1
Sequence Number: 2 exp 2
Ack sent 2
Ack sent 0
Ack sent 1
Ack sent 2
Sequence Number: 3 exp 3
Ack sent 3
Sequence Number: 4 exp 4
Ack sent 4
Sequence Number: 5 exp 5
Ack sent 5
Ack sent 3
Ack sent 4
Ack sent 5
Sequence Number: 6 exp 6
Ack sent 6
Sequence Number: 7 exp 7
Ack sent 7
Sequence Number: 8 exp 8
Ack sent 8
Ack sent 6
Ack sent 7
Ack sent 8
Ack sent 6
Ack sent 7
Ack sent 8
Sequence Number: 9 exp 9
Ack sent 9
Sequence Number: 10 exp 10
Ack sent 10
Sequence Number: 11 exp 11
Ack sent 11
Ack sent 9
Ack sent 10
Ack sent 11
Ack sent 9
Ack sent 10
Ack sent 11
Sequence Number: 12 exp 12
Ack sent 12
Ack sent 10
Ack sent 11
Ack sent 12
Sequence Number: 13 exp 13
Ack sent 13
Sequence Number: 14 exp 14
Ack sent 14
Ack sent 13
Ack sent 14
Ack sent 13
Ack sent 14
File upload finished!
Server: Sending IP used: 127.0.0.1
Server: Sending port used: 62073
Server: closesocket() is OK
Server: Cleaning up...
Server: WSACleanup() is OK
```

Here is my client output

```
Client: The Winsock DLL status is Running.
Client: socket() is OK!
File upload started...
0
1
2
Sequence number 0 timeouted!
Sequence number 0 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 1 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 2 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 0 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 1 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 2 acknowledgement received
3
4
5
Sequence number 3 timeouted!
Sequence number 3 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 4 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 5 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 3 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 4 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 5 acknowledgement received
6
7
8
Sequence number 6 timeouted!
Sequence number 6 timeouted!
Sequence number 6 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 7 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 8 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 6 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 7 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 8 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 6 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 7 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 8 acknowledgement received
9
10
11
Sequence number 9 timeouted!
Sequence number 9 timeouted!
Sequence number 9 acknowledgement received
12
Sequence number 10 timeouted!
Sequence number 10 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 11 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 9 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 10 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 11 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 9 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 10 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 11 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 12 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 10 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 11 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 12 acknowledgement received
13
14
Sequence number 13 timeouted!
Sequence number 13 timeouted!
Sequence number 13 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 14 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 13 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 14 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 13 acknowledgement received
Sequence number 14 acknowledgement received
Client: Sending IP(s) used: 0.0.0.0
Client: Sending port used: 62073
Client: Receiving IP used: 127.0.0.1
Client: Receiving port used: 8080
Client: Finished sending. Closing the sending socket...
Server: closesocket() is OK
Client: Cleaning up...
Client: WSACleanup() is OK
```

The client reads a file part by part and sends a block of defined size to server at a time. The client window size is 3 currently, so it waits for all 3 blocks in the window to be acknowledged before moving ahead. Server receives a block and immediately sends an acknowledgement.
Why does the blocks get timeout even though server is sending ackowledgement immediately? Also, client is getting ackowledgement message only after it sends 3 blocks, why is that so? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Before I read through this could you say why you are reinventing TCP/IP ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I am learning UDP. so, I thought doing such task will help me better understand UDP as well as `winsock2` library